# Adding comments like facebook with django and jquery

Tags: jquery, django, comments

I am working on a project with django and jquery and i have to implement comments like facebook and i dont have idea how to do it. Please i need your help and need you to be very specific with the code because i am a newbie.

Here is the code please tell me what i am missing.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#category_form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url pos.views.add_category %}',
        data: $('#category_form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
          location.reload();
    $('#category_form').get(0).reset();
      },
     });
     return false;
     });
    });
</script>
```

Form

```
    class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label=(u'Categoria'))
    class Meta:
     model = Category
```

Urls

```
    url(r'^category/$', 'pos.views.Categories'),
```

View

```
    def add_comment(request):
     if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
      category_form = CategoryForm(request.POST)
      if category_form.is_valid():
       category = category_form.save(commit=True)
       category.save()
       json = simplejson.dumps(category, ensure_ascii=False)
       return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
    return render_to_response(simplejson.dumps({'category': category,}),        context_instance=RequestContext(request), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: try something on your own and post the code for better suggestions.

Comment: i have found a lot of info but using php not django and i dont have idea how to start. I have a little experience with django but just starting with jquery.

Comment: to each his own, if you are good at php, then try zend, instead of python.

Comment: the project is required with python ... the question is after saving data how can i show comments on same page without refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view has two returns

```
return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
return render_to_response(simplejson.dumps({'category': category,}),        context_instance=RequestContext(request), mimetype='application/json')
```

Get rid of the one you don't need. (It's hard to tell what you need from the poorly formatted code.)

Read the jQuery docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Specifically, check out the **Callback Function Queues** section

Change your javascript so ajax does something like this instead:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url pos.views.add_category %}',
        data: $('#category_form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#results").html(data);
        }
            ...
```

This uses the success callback to set the returned data (the json returned from your view) as the html data of the element with the ID "results" in your HTML.

Comment: Aaron thanks for your help. i am not sure about which url must be on the ajax .. i actually have the view that is responsible of adding objects to database is that ok? and then how the view will populate the data that is stored in database?

Answer (score 0):

I think for posting comment main problem you will be having is with the login, before that you need to authorize user, for authorizing user you can use [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth).

As you told that after save you want to do something, you can do it by overriding save function in model. For eg

```
class Updates(models.Model) 
    ...........
    ...........

    def save():
        super(save())
        ....................
        # Do your job here
        ....................
```

Thanks

Comment: my problem is that i dont know how to return the results after saving in database without refresh page

Comment: as per ur requirements i did the changes, check it out